# Hibernate Incorrect datetime value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, datetime, spring-data

Hoping someone can clear this up for me. I'm getting some warnings when I run a unit test that is using hibernate criteria. The specific warnings are:

```
Mar 10, 2016 11:48:31 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$StandardWarningHandler logWarning
WARN: SQL Warning Code: 1292, SQLState: 22007
Mar 10, 2016 11:48:31 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$StandardWarningHandler logWarning
WARN: Incorrect datetime value: '1454684370' for column 'date_created' at row 1
Mar 10, 2016 11:48:31 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$StandardWarningHandler logWarning
WARN: SQL Warning Code: 1292, SQLState: 22007
Mar 10, 2016 11:48:31 AM  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$StandardWarningHandler logWarning
WARN: Incorrect datetime value: '1454684700' for column 'date_created' at row 1
```

I can't figure out what Hibernate is complaining about. The column it's talking about, 'date_created', is of type datetime. I've tried passing in every other version of the date object, a string, a java.util.Date, a java.sql.Timestamp, but those just cause actual errors. Specifically they cause:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.sql.Timestamp cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

or, of course, whatever other type I tried passing instead of Long. The times I'm passing in are epoch times but for some reason I'm getting these errors and the unit tests aren't passing.

Also, in case it might help, here is the specific code in the tests:

```
public List<Content> findByCollectionName(String collectionName, Long exclusiveBegin, Long inclusiveEnd, Long expiration)
{
    if(collectionName == null)
        return null;

    Session session = currentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Content.class).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    criteria.createAlias("collections", "cols");
    criteria
        .add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("cols.name", collectionName), buildCriterion(exclusiveBegin, inclusiveEnd, expiration)));

    List<Content> list = criteria.list();

    session.getTransaction().commit();

    return list;
}

private Criterion buildCriterion(Long exclusiveBegin, Long inclusiveEnd, Long expiration)
{
    List<Criterion> criterion = new ArrayList<Criterion>();
    if(exclusiveBegin != null)
        criterion.add(Restrictions.gt("dateCreated", exclusiveBegin));
    if(inclusiveEnd != null)
        criterion.add(Restrictions.le("dateCreated", inclusiveEnd));
    if(expiration != null)
        criterion.add(Restrictions.ge("dateCreated", expiration));

    Criterion[] array = new Criterion[criterion.size()];
    for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
    {
        array[j] = criterion.get(j);
    }

    return Restrictions.and(array);
}
```

**EDIT Sorry for the delay, here's the requested additions.**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "content")
public class Content implements Serializable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8483381938400121236L;

public Content()
{
}

public Content(String messageId, ContentBlock block) throws NullPointerException
{
    if(messageId == null || block == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("Null objects passed for Content object creation");
    this.messageId = messageId;
    this.setContentBlock(block);
    this.dateCreated = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED")
private int id;

@Column(name = "message_id")
private String messageId;

@Column(name = "date_created")
private long dateCreated;

@Column(name = "content_wrapper", columnDefinition = "longblob")
private byte[] contentWrapper;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "contentBlocks")
private List<TCollection> collections;

/*@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "message_id")
private TMessage message;*/
```

**I omitted the getters and setters for brevity**

As for the database, it's got a regular structure. The TContent table has:

```
column               type
id                  bigint
user_id             int
name                varchar
date_created        datetime
collection_wrapper  longblob
tspoll_expire       decimal
```

Please let me know if I can add anything else or have missed anything. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Have you tried annotating your column with @TemporalType(TIMESTAMP) (may or may not be necessary) and then using java.sql.Timestamp?

Comment: As I mentioned, trying anything other than a Long results in an error. To be more explicit, it results in a ClassCastException saying whatever it is cannot be cast to a Long. So it has to be a long. The problem is why won't hibernate accept it.

Comment: Can you post your model?

Comment: Please add mapping for `Content` class and database table structure for this class.

Comment: Like the other comments here, I believe that the problem lies in a mapping problem (either annotation or XML file). Can you post your mapping here?

Comment: and one more question - how you creates database structure?  Using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the past I've used the following, which successfully converts between MySQL datetime field and `java.util.Date`:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateTime;
```

And more recently with [Joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), the following successfully converts between MySQL 5.7 datetime(3) and `org.joda.time.DateTime`:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "DATETIME(3)")
private DateTime dateTime;
```

There will be other options but these are the two I'm currently familiar with.

Comment: Well I looked more into the model class and the datetime variable was a Long, so that may well have been the major cause of the problem. I refactored it to a Timestamp and it seemed to at least start working with hibernate. So I suppose that was the answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate has a bug (sort of) when parameter `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` set to `update` If table contains filed with the same name, for example from previous deployment, it just leave field 'as is' and doesn't change field type. 
I think, previously you set `date_created` as Date type, but later switch it to long.

Possible solutions:

1. change java bean field type `long dateCreated`; to `Date dateCreated;` and work with Date type in code.
2. manually change database structure accordinly to your java classes. `alter table content alter column date_created TYPE bigint` I doesn't sure mysql allow to do it, in that case you should write migration procedure.
3. drop database and recreate it with hibernate (only if content not important/test/garbage)

Comment: Thank you. I believe you're right that was essentially the problem. Sorry but Mr. Chambers answer had already managed to lead be, though a bit round a bout, to that answer so I had already accepted his solution. Thank you for the help though.